# How to group list items based on common items in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have below `list` which contains `tuples`:

```
mylist = [(0, 2), (1, 2), (1, 3)]
```

As we can see from above list, item 0 `(0, 2)` and item 1 `(1, 2)` has common  number `2` and item 1 `(1, 2)` and item 2 `(1, 3)` has common number `1`, so how can I create a new list or reformat the existing list such that it looks like below:

```
my_new_list = [(0, 1, 2), (1, 2, 3)]
```

`mylist` can have `n` number of items (tuples) in it.

Comment: Please clarify more about the question? you want to get them 2 by 2? sequential ? how ?

Comment: @MehrdadPedramfar  Edited the code. I don't want to get them 2 by 2 but just want to group them based on common numbers in each tuple.?

Comment: Are you comparing any two items only if they adjacent to each other or to all others? For example, what if item[0] was `(3,2)` would you group it (also) with item[2]?

Comment: @JackFleeting Apologies forgot to mention this but yes comparing with all others in the list

Comment: So, in that case, `my_new_list` would have 3 elements in it?

Comment: @JackFleeting Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. I modified `mylist` a bit to be more representative of the problem:

```
mylist = [(3, 2), (1, 2),(8,9), (1, 3),(2,4)] 
my_new_list = []
for l in mylist:
    ind = mylist.index(l)
    stub= mylist[ind+1:]
    if ind<=len(mylist)-2:
        for s in stub:
            inter = set(l).intersection(set(s))
            if len(inter)>0:
                my_new_list.append(set(l+s))
my_new_list
```

Edit:
To convert each element of `my_new_list` to tuple, use:

```
for i in range(len(my_new_list)):
   my_new_list[i]=tuple(my_new_list[i])
```

Output:

```
[{1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 2, 4}]
```

Comment: The resulting list contains `set` and not `tuple`. Is there any way we can make it `tuple`